# Counting some binary trees with lots of extra stucture

Tags: co.combinatorics, generating-functions, recurrences, trees, binary-tree

While working on some computations on Hilbert schemes, I came across the following combinatorial problem.

Let $D(k,n)$ be the weighted number of binary trees (children are left/right) with $n$ internal nodes (internal node = node with children), with each node labeled by an integer (labels need not be unique, negatives are allowed), with the root labeled $k$, and the label of each internal node is equal to the sum of the labels of the children, and each leaf is labeled either $1$ or $-1$. The weight (which may be negative) assigned to such a tree is the product of the labels of the internal nodes. Furthermore, there is an ordering of the internal nodes such that a parent always comes before a child.

For example, $D(1,2) = 4$, with the trees

```
      1
    2  -1
   1 1
```

and

```
     1
  -1  2
     1 1
```

each counted with weight 2 (and each of these has only one possible ordering of the internal nodes).

In the end, I'm actually only interested in the sequence $D(1,2i)$. This sequence appears to be http://oeis.org/A151403, which counts a certain type of lattice paths in the first quadrant, and is equal to $4^i$ times the $i^{th}$ Catalan number.

But I defined $D(k,n)$ because then you can get the recurrence relation
$$
 D(k,n) = k \sum_{a+b=k} \sum_{c+d=n-1} \binom{n-1}{c} D(a,c) D(b,d) 
$$
where $c,d \ge 0$ but $a,b$ are any integers. We have initial conditions $D(\pm1,0) = 1$ and $D(k,0) = 0$ otherwise. It is easy to see that $D(k,n) = 0$ if $|k| > n+1$, so the sum here is finite.

(Each child node starts a new tree, the factor of $k$ takes care of the weight, and the $\binom{n-1}{c}$ is the number of ways of "interweaving" the ordering.)

With some computation, I was able to guess the formula for $D(k,n)$. 
We have 
$$
 D(k,k-1) = 2 (2k)^{k-2}
$$
and if $n-k+1 \neq 0$, then 
$$
D(k,n) = (2k)^n \binom{n}{\frac{n-k-1}{2}} \frac{2}{n-k+1}
$$
(where the binomial coefficient is 0 if $\frac{n-k-1}{2}$ is not an integer or is negative).

How can I prove the formula for $D(1,2i)$?

(1) I could try to use induction and the recurrence formula, but that seems messy.

(2) It seems more nice to provide a bijection between these funny trees and the lattice paths or something on the A151403 page. But this seems tricky with the weights (especially since some are negative).

(3) I can turn the recurrence relation into a two variable generating function and [get a PDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2331695/solve-a-first-order-non-linear-pde-or-just-find-a-residue-of-the-solution), but it doesn't look like I can get a solution explicit enough to be useful.

I though I would ask in case this is well known to someone with more experience in tree/lattice path counting.

Comment: If I define a power series $R\in \mathbb{Q}\left[t,t^{-1}\right]\left[\left[x\right]\right]$ by $R = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \sum\limits_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} Q\left(n,k\right) t^k \dfrac{x^n}{\left(n-1\right)!}$, then it satisfies $R = x \left(t \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} R^2 + \left(t + t^{-1}\right)\right)$, right? Maybe Lagrange inversion is not totally hopeless (particularly since there is such a thing as noncommutative Lagrange inversion, which *might* allow us to treat both $t \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}$ and $t + t^{-1}$ as some kind of scalars).

Comment: By $Q(n,k)$ you mean $D(k,n)$? I don't think that is quite right, e.g. R should have some degree 0 part in $x$. I believe the equation in the link is correct. In particular, I don't know how to get away with a derivative in only one variable.

Comment: Oops, yes, I mean $D\left(k,n\right)$. But the differential equation looks right to me; it follows straight from your recursing. Why should there be a constant term?

Comment: I was thinking that $D(\pm1,0)$ should give terms $x^0t$ and $x^0t^{-1}$. But I guess you are starting your sum at $n=1$? Another question: From your differential equation, it seems that the term $xt$ appears in $R$, which implies that $D(1,1)=1$. But $D(1,1)=0$.

Comment: Oh! Maybe it should be $R = x \left( t \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} R^2 + \left(t^2 + t^{-2}\right) \right)$. Sorry for this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to find an interesting generalization of your formula, but I'm having trouble finding a reference in the literature.

Let's call a 0-1-2 tree, a rooted tree where every vertex can have no child, a left child, a right child, or both. Let's call such a tree increasing if we also have a total ordering on the vertices where each parent is less than their child. We will denote by $B_n$ the set of increasing 0-1-2 trees on $n$ vertices. There is an obvious way to append $n+1$ new leaves to a tree $T\in B_n$ to make it a full binary tree where the internal vertices correspond exactly to the vertex set of $T$. Let's call this binary tree $\tilde{T}$.

Suppose we associate a variable $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n+1}$ to each leaf. Then every vertex in $\tilde{T}$ has a weighted hook-length given by the sum of the variables associated to each leaf it covers (i.e., to each leaf that is a descendant of this vertex). The weight of $\tilde{T}$ is the product of these hook-lengths over all internal vertices. Let's define a polynomial $\tilde{T}(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n+1})$ to be the sum of the weight of $\tilde{T}$ over all permutations of $x_1,\dots,x_{n+1}$.

For example starting with the tree in $B_2$

```
      1
    2
```

we can extend it to

```
      1          1          1          1          1          1
    2  z   ,   2  z   ,   2  y   ,   2  y   ,   2  x   ,   2  x
   x y        y x        x z        z x        y z        z y
```

so its polynomial is 
$$\tilde{T}(x,y,z)=\sum_{\text{Sym}}(x+y)(x+y+z)=4(x+y+z)^2.$$ 
We can define 
$$F_n(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{n+1})=\sum_{T\in B_n}\tilde{T}(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n+1}),$$
so that, for example, $F_2(x_1,x_2,x_3)=8(x_1+x_2+x_3)^2$, by the above. We also regard the empty graph as a 0-1-2 tree, with weight $1$.

Now we can state the result in general:

**Theorem:** For all $n\in \mathbb N$ we have the following identity 
$$F_n(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n+1})=2^n n!(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n+1})^{n}.$$

**Proof:** Let $\mathcal P'$ be the set of subsets of $\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n+1}\}$ except for the empty set and the full set. First we notice that the root of a binary tree $\tilde{T}$ always has hook-length $(x_1+\cdots +x_{n+1})$. Next notice that two increasing 0-1-2 trees of sizes $a,b$, respectively, combine together to form another 0-1-2 tree of size $a+b+1$, but the ordering can be extended in $\frac{(a+b)!}{a!b!}$ ways. This gives us the recurrence
$$F_n(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{n+1})=(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n+1})\sum_{S\in \mathcal P'}\binom{n-1}{|S|-1}F_{|S|-1}(S)F_{n-|S|}(S^{c}).$$

This will allow us to prove our theorem inductively.

From here we will make use of the weighted Cayley formula for labeled trees on a set $S={1,2,\dots,p}$, which can be obtained from the matrix tree theorem. It says that 
$$y_1y_2\cdots y_p(y_1+y_2+\cdots+y_p)^{p-2}=\sum_{T}y_1^{\deg 1}\cdots y_p^{\deg p}$$
where the sum on the right runs over all labeled trees and keeps track of the degree of each vertex. If instead we enumerated *rooted* labeled trees and thought of the root as having a "half edge" (so its degree is increased by 1) then we get $y_1y_2\cdots y_p(y_1+y_2+\cdots+y_p)^{p-1}$. Now a tree on the vertex set $\{1,2,\dots,n+1\}$ can be constructed by making a rooted tree on vertex sets $S\in \mathcal P$ and $S^{c}$ and then joining the roots. This way a tree is constructed exactly $2n$ times: because there are $n$ edges to choose for the splitting, and then ordering the two subsets.

So by Cayley's formula we get
$$\sum_{S\in \mathcal P}\left(\prod_{i\in S}x_i\left(\sum_{i\in S}x_{i}\right)^{|S|-1}\cdot\prod_{i \in S^c}x_i\left(\sum_{i\in S^{c}}x_i\right)^{n-|S|}\right)=2nx_1x_2\cdots x_{n+1}(x_1+\cdots+x_{n+1})^{n-1}$$
$$\iff \sum_{S\in \mathcal P}\left(\left(\sum_{i\in S}x_{i}\right)^{|S|-1}\cdot\left(\sum_{i\in S^{c}}x_i\right)^{n-|S|}\right)=2n(x_1+\cdots+x_{n+1})^{n-1}$$ 
which tells us
$$(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n+1})\sum_{S\in \mathcal P'}\binom{n-1}{|S|-1}F_{|S|-1}(S)F_{n-|S|}(S^{c})=2^nn!(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n+1})^n$$
giving us the induction step. $\blacksquare$

---

Now to get to your problem we will put $\frac{n+k+1}{2}$ of the variables equal to $1$, and the remaining ones to $-1$. This is equivalent to enforcing the root to be labeled $k$ in your notation. However my function
$$F_n(1,\dots,1,-1,\dots,-1)=2^nn!k^n$$ enumerates the variables as distinct so we have to divide by $\left(\frac{n+k+1}{2}\right)!\left(\frac{n-k+1}{2}\right)!$ in order to make the 1's indistinguishable, and similarly for the -1's. Finally we can say for your function
$$D(k,n)=\frac{(2k)^nn!}{\left(\frac{n+k+1}{2}\right)!\left(\frac{n-k+1}{2}\right)!}$$
as you had predicted.

Comment: There may be an issue in the proof of the Theorem, due to the fact that binary trees are not exactly trees; they also have a left-right distinction for the two children of each vertex. Maybe there are some missing $2^n$ factors around, although I think the tweaks should be easy. (Sorry for vagueness; I'm time-constrained.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg In the proof of the theorem we only use binary trees for setting up the recursive identity, which does depend on the left/right distinction. Then after stating the identity we need to prove, we use calculations with general labeled trees.

Comment: I haven't had the leisure to think carefully about the combinatorics here, but I just wanted to mention that there is an alternative pathway from the recurrence in the proof of your Theorem to your Theorem. Namely, once you have that recurrence for $F_n$, it suffices to prove that the right hand side satisfies a ...

Comment: ... parallel recurrence: parallel recurrence: $2^n n! \left(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n+1}\right)^n$ $= \left(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n+1}\right) $ $ \sum_{S \in \mathcal{P}'} \dbinom{n-1}{\left|S\right|-1} 2^{\left|S\right|-1} \left(\left|S\right|-1\right)! \left(\sum_{x \in S} x\right)^{\left|S\right|-1} 2^{\left|S^c \right|-1} \left(\left|S^c\right|-1\right)! \left(\sum_{x \in S^c} x\right)^{\left|S^c\right|-1}$. This recurrence easily boils do the following ...

Comment: Darij, thanks! I was really hoping there was a quicker algebraic proof.

Comment: ... simpler identity: $n \left(x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_{n+1}\right)^{n-1} = \sum \left(x_S + x_{n+1}\right)^{\left|S\right|} \left(x_{S'}\right)^{\left|S'\right|}$, where the sum is over all nonempty subsets $S'$ of $\left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$ (not $\left\{1,2,\ldots,n+1\right\}$), and where we use the notations $S' = \left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\} \setminus S$ and $x_S = \sum_{s \in S} x_s$. And this is a neat generalization of Abel's identity which should fall prey to the same methods.