# Proving a particular "Abel type" identiy

Tags: co.combinatorics, hypergeometric-functions, combinatorial-identities

I have reduced solving [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272820/counting-some-binary-trees-with-lots-of-extra-stucture) to proving the following identity, for $n, \ell \ge 0$:
$$
 (n-2\ell+1)^{n-1}  \binom{n}{\ell-1}  = 
\\ \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n_1+n_2=n-1}\left[ (n_1+1)^{n_1-1} (n_2-2\ell+1)^{n_2} \binom{n_2}{\ell-1}  + \\
 \ell \sum_{\ell_1+\ell_2=\ell} \left[(n_1-2\ell_1+1)^{n_1} \binom{n_1}{\ell_1-1} \frac{1}{\ell_1} (n_2-2\ell_2+1)^{n_2} \binom{n_2}{\ell_2-1} \frac{1}{\ell_2}\right] + (n_2+1)^{n_2-1} (n_1-2\ell+1)^{n_1} \binom{n_1}{\ell-1} \right]
$$
where $n_1,n_2$ and non-negative integers and $\ell_1, \ell_2$ are positve integers.

I have checked this computationally for small values of $n$ and $\ell$, and it seems to be good.

It is not hypergeometric, but I think it may be "Abel-type" in the sense of [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.24.8449&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

How could I prove an identity like this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a starter. We can simplify the RHS somewhat.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{2}& \sum_{{n_1+n_2=n-1}\atop{n_1,n_2\geq 0}}\left[ (n_1+1)^{n_1-1} (n_2-2\ell+1)^{n_2} \binom{n_2}{\ell-1}\right.\\
> &\quad  + \ell \sum_{{\ell_1+\ell_2=\ell}\atop{\ell_1,\ell_2\geq 1}} (n_1-2\ell_1+1)^{n_1} \binom{n_1}{\ell_1-1} \frac{1}{\ell_1} (n_2-2\ell_2+1)^{n_2} \binom{n_2}{\ell_2-1} \frac{1}{\ell_2}\\
> &\quad\left. + (n_2+1)^{n_2-1} (n_1-2\ell+1)^{n_1} \binom{n_1}{\ell-1} \right]\\
> &=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{{n_1+n_2=n-1}\atop{n_1,n_2\geq 0}}\left[ (n_1+1)^{n_1-1} (n_2-2\ell+1)^{n_2} \binom{n_2+1}{\ell}\frac{\ell}{n_2+1}\right.\\
> &\quad  + \frac{\ell}{(n_1+1)(n_2+1)} \sum_{{\ell_1+\ell_2=\ell}\atop{\ell_1,\ell_2\geq 1}}(n_1-2\ell_1+1)^{n_1} \binom{n_1+1}{\ell_1} (n_2-2\ell_2+1)^{n_2} \binom{n_2+1}{\ell_2}\\
> &\quad\left. + (n_2+1)^{n_2-1} (n_1-2\ell+1)^{n_1} \binom{n_1+1}{\ell}\frac{\ell}{n_1+1} \right]\\
> &\color{blue}{=\frac{\ell}{2} \sum_{{n_1+n_2=n-1}\atop{n_1,n_2\geq 0}}\frac{1}{(n_1+1)(n_2+1)}}\\
> &\quad\quad\color{blue}{\cdot\sum_{{\ell_1+\ell_2=\ell}\atop{\ell_1,\ell_2\geq 0}}(n_1-2\ell_1+1)^{n_1} \binom{n_1+1}{\ell_1} (n_2-2\ell_2+1)^{n_2} \binom{n_2+1}{\ell_2}}\\
> \end{align*}
>   In the first step we use the binomial identity $\binom{n}{k-1}\frac{1}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k}\frac{1}{n+1}$. In the second step we collect all terms and start the inner sum with indices $\ell_1,\ell_2\geq 0$.

Note: I could not verify the equality of LHS and RHS for all small values. In case of $n=3,l=2$ the LHS $$(n-2\ell+1)^{n-1}  \binom{n}{\ell-1}=(3-4+1)^2\binom{3}{1}=0$$ while the RHS is $2$ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: The table of lhs-rhs shows growing discrepancy,$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -2 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
 2 & -8 & 12 & -8 & -30 \\
 39 & -61 & 6 & -122 & 195 \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: I omitted a factor of $\binom{n-1}{n_1}$ right after the first summation. That is probably causing the discrepancy. Sorry about that! I did get an answer to my original (linked) question, so that also answers this one.

Comment: @Drew: No worries. Good that your question could be answered and thanks for the info.